# After deleting folders older than X days I get ERROR

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I used this command:

```
FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

to delete all folders older than 10 days ,
and it is working fine.

problem is that I get an error and it's failing my build:

**ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.**

I need to be able to exit with ERRORLEVEL=0.

Answer (score 0):

Add `echo` before the command to see what's wrong (maybe it's trying to delete a subfolder of an already deleted folder):

```
FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir==TRUE echo @path & rd /S /Q @path"
```

Or you can simply make it fail-proof by explicitly checking if the folder exists:

```
FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir==TRUE if exist @path rd /S /Q @path"
```

BTW, `forfiles` method doesn't seem reliable as a folder date isn't updated for its 'grandchild' files. I would use robocopy in list-mode to generate the list of old files and then process it: get the folder path of each file and delete it if it still exists.

Comment: This is what I get:
"C:\Test\inner_test\dfgdf"
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

And this is the folder that was deleted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but now  with checking with "exists" I'm getting ERRORLEVEL=1 when he doesn't have folders to delete.

ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
exit 1

Comment: And what's wrong with that? You can hide the message by adding `>nul 2>nul` after the closing quote.

Comment: I want to get "exit 0" in both cases: if files had been deleted & if there wasn't any files that were deleted. the >nul 2>nul may hide the massage but I still get "exit 1" when he doesn't find files to delete.

Comment: So it's like writing "exit 0" at the end of the script.

Comment: Do you know how I can do it with if-else, meaning if it find files to delete delete them, and if it doesn't find i will give him ver>nul as you suggested.

Comment: Try the reversed order of comparison `FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c if exist @path IF @isdir==TRUE rd /S /Q @path"` or with if-else: `FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c if exist @path (IF @isdir==TRUE rd /S /Q @path) else (ver>nul)"`